# Exclude country file folder and file names in VB script

Tags: vbscript

I need your help how to exclude specific country filenames for given folder.

```
    DIM datasource

    datasource = objRs.Fields(0).Value
    Region =  replace(objRs.Fields(1).Value," ","_",1,-1,0)
    CountryCode = Region &"_"& serialNumber1
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------
    'Region subfolder creation              
    packageCountryDataPath = outputfolder&"\"& Region
    If  Not fso.FolderExists(packageCountryDataPath) Then
        fso.CreateFolder(packageCountryDataPath)
        WScript.Echo "Regions Folders created: " & Region & ""
    End If
```

I want to exlcude only specific country folders like UN & MA. I dont want to generate these folders

```
Do Until objRs.EOF
    datasource = objRs.Fields(0).Value
    WScript.Echo datasource
    Region =  replace(objRs.Fields(1).Value," ","_",1,-1,0)
    CountryCode = Region &"_"& serialNumber1
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------
    'Region subfolder creation              
    packageCountryDataPath = outputfolder&"\"& Region
    If  Not fso.FolderExists(packageCountryDataPath) Then
        fso.CreateFolder(packageCountryDataPath)
        WScript.Echo "Regions Folders created: " & Region & ""
    End If
    WScript.Echo "Regions Folders created: " & packageCountryDataPath & ""

    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(Inputfile)
    Set files = folder.Files
    For each item In files
      If Instr(item.Path,".xml") <> 0 then  
         logfilename =item.Name
        logfilename= replace(logfilename,".xml","",1,-1,0)  
          returnValue = exportDatasource(item.Path,logfolder&"\"& logfilename &".log", datasource, CountryCode, DateTime, utilsfolder, packageCountryDataPath, dbDataSource, dbLogin, dbPassword)                    
        If returnValue = 0 Then
            'WScript.Echo "Datasource " & Region & " processed"
        Else
            WScript.Echo "Error while processing Datasource " & Region
            Exit Do
        End If
      End If
```

Kindly let us know how to do this.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: provide some example of filenames to be included and excluded.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: How is `outputfolder` defined?

Comment: Hi,REG_20170302_150655 is the folder name and under this folder there are country folders will be generated (sub folders).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options

1. Use a Where clause in the SQL statement that obtained the recordset.
2. Use InStr( "|aa|bb|...|zz|", "|" & Region & "|" ) on a white or black list of country codes ([???](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm)).
3. Use a Dictionary and d.Exists(Region) to determine whether a Region is a element of such a list.

cf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207316/how-to-check-if-variable-in-array-in-vbscript)