# How can I search an array in VBScript for my IF Statement

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to build a VBScript function that will have an IF statement where I want to determine if there is a match of values between a specified value and values populating an array. Below is simplified snippet of code to get the general functionality across.

```
Dim val1
Dim arr1(5)

val1 = 1234
arr1(0) = 1111
arr1(1) = 2222
arr1(2) = 1234
arr1(3) = 1444
arr1(4) = 1337

if val1 = '''some value in the array (in this case arr1(2))''' then
    '''do nothing, end if'''
else
    '''engage the API in the object model I'm working in to perform a function'''
end if
```

I'm not sure what I put in the area where I want to see if `val1` is within `arr1`. If it is within it, I want to end the loop. If it is not within it, I want to perform some function in the object model that I'm working with. Can someone help me with the syntax of the if statement?

Comment: If you want to search in array, you will have to rely on loop. If you switch to dictionary, you may use .Exists method to check for values without any loop. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207316/how-to-check-if-variable-in-array-in-vbscript

Answer (score -2):

You can simply loop the array, and stop the loop once you find what you are looking for

```
Dim val1
Dim arr1(5)

val1 = 1234
arr1(0) = 1111
arr1(1) = 2222
arr1(2) = 1234
arr1(3) = 1444
arr1(4) = 1337

dim valueInArray
dim foundIt
foundIt = false 'initialize on false

'find the value in the array
for each valueInArray in arr1
    if valueInArray = val1 then
        foundIt = true
        exit for 'stop looping once we found it
    end if
next

if not foundIt then
    '''engage the API in the object model I'm working in to perform a function'''
end if
```

You could also use dictionary object and use the `Exists` method to figure out if a value is in that list, but that would be overhead for such a simple case.

Comment: There's plenty of existing answers to this exact problem in [How to check if variable in array in vbscript](//stackoverflow.com/q/42207316). Would suggest you post your answer there if it's not [already covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42231338/692942).